# Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

While trying to execute the below query

```
Declare @t table (id int, string varchar(1000))

INSERT INTO @t (id, string)
SELECT 1, 'zxzzxx,ppppbppp,trtrtr,tyyt,hgghh,fefew,rewr,rwerer' 

;WITH test (id, lft, rght, idx)
AS 
(
        SELECT t.id
                ,LEFT(t.string, CHARINDEX(', ', t.string) - 1)
                ,SUBSTRING(t.string, CHARINDEX(', ', t.string) + 2, DATALENGTH(t.string))
                ,0
        FROM @t t
        UNION ALL
        SELECT c.id
                ,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(', ', c.rght) = 0 THEN c.rght ELSE LEFT(c.rght, CHARINDEX(', ', c.rght) - 1) END
                ,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(', ', c.rght) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(c.rght, CHARINDEX(', ', c.rght) + 2, DATALENGTH(c.rght)) 
                        ELSE '' END
                ,idx + 1
        FROM test c 
        WHERE DATALENGTH(c.rght) > 0
)

select id, lft from test
```

I am getting the below error

```
Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 8
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
```

but the same works for SELECT 1, 'the, quick, brown, fox, jumped, over, the, lazy, dog'

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a space missing between your words.

You are currently looking for charindex of `', '` not `','`.

And the string does not have any match of `', '`.

Answer (score 2):

This Error message happens usually when you do these steps;

- When you use [Substring](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-substring.html),
  [left](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx), [right](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx) functions.

  When you use [CharIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) (used in
  the field, the selected word or word
  search, or the length of a character
  to be inadequate)

The return value is returned to each server in the query expression, the result of the transaction `0` (zero) returns, if error returns `-1`

This will not result in errors for the server to return a value of -1 or are compared objects.

Comment: I faced that problem and solved this way: `select left(value,charindex('-',value)) from table where value like '%-%' `. The where condition `value like '%-%'` assures us that there won't any result without character '-' searched in our charindex function, and their return value will always be positive.